# "Mir ist Angst!" - "Wie bitte, was ist dir?"

Tags: capitalization

Der Zwiebelfisch empfiehlt die Schreibweise "Mir ist angst.", weil "angst" antwortet auf die Frage "Wie ist mir?".

Andererseits halte ich die Frage "Was ist dir?" ebenfalls für angebracht, zumindest in der gesprochenen Sprache. Dann wäre "Angst" Subjekt eines Satzes mit Inversion.

Hat der Zwiebelfisch hier das letzte Wort?

EDIT:
Hier der Link zum Zwiebelfisch: [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-angst-angst-a-309632.html).

Comment: Der Zwiebelfisch ist sowieso **immer** mit Vorsicht zu genießen (ich lass die Doppeldeutigkeit mal so stehen).

Comment: Ich bin zutiefst beängstigt. Zum Glück gibt es nur wenige Google Hits dafür, das klingt für mich nämlich eher wie eine schlechte Übersetzung auf dem Russischen. - Wobei mir die Redewendung geläufig ist.

Comment: @Martin Danke, steht tatsächlich so da :/ ... Die Suchmaschine wirft für "Mir ist/wird angst" (ohne "und bange") nur sehr wenige Treffer aus, v.a. aus der Luther-Bibel. Ich würde es als unüblich ansehen und nicht verwenden.

Answer (score 4):

Hier gibt es klare Aussagen zur Rechtschreibung in den *[amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/)* des [Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](https://web.archive.org/web/20161022124249/http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html):

> **§ 55 Substantive schreibt man groß.**
>   [...] Angst haben, jemandem Angst (und Bange) machen [...]
>
> **§ 56 Klein schreibt man Wörter, die formgleich als Substantive vorkommen, aber selbst keine substantivischen Merkmale aufweisen.**
>   1. Wörter, die vorwiegend prädikativ gebraucht werden, wie *angst, bange, feind, freund, gram, klasse, leid, pleite, recht, schuld, spitze, unrecht, weh* in Verbindung mit den Verben *sein, bleiben* oder *werden*.
>   *Beispiele: **Mir wird angst. Uns ist angst und bange.** Wir sind ihr gram. Sein Spiel ist klasse. Mir ist das alles leid. Die Firma ist pleite. Das ist mir recht.*

Somit ist es nicht verwunderlich, dass auch Wörterbücher wie der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bange), [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Denominalisierung.html) und [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/angst_und_bange_sein) die Kleinschreibung empfehlen.

In der Wendung *"Mir ist angst"* handelt es ich also um solch ein verblasstes Nomen **in Verbindung mit dem Verb *"sein"***. Im Gebrauch als Substantiv hieße es richtig *"Ich habe Angst"* und die Frage dazu lautete dann *"Was hast Du?*".

Das erwähnte Zitat einer Empfehlung aus dem Zwiebelfisch habe ich leider nicht gefunden.

Comment: Ja, "angst und bange" ist eine feste Redewendung. Aber "Mir ist/wird angst." lese ich hier zum ersten Mal.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: das ist ja das Schöne an dem Beispiel, es gibt trotz Redewendung beides: *"Angst und Bange"* wie auch *"angst und bange"* ;)

Comment: Sowohl _angst_ als auch _bange_ sind oft austauschbar. In alten Büchern findet man durchaus Sätze wie "Mir ward (himmel)angst." oder "Ihm wurde bange". Im Präsens kenne ich kein "Mir ist angst", wohl aber das "Mir ist bange" oder "Mir ist angst und bange".